# Is strict aliasing still something to think about in C?

Tags: c, gcc, strict-aliasing

I recently read a [well-known article by Mike Acton about strict aliasing](https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) and how we should use it to increase performance significantly in C code.

It seems to be simple, in some cases, that if you tell your compiler that there will not be two ways to access to your data, then the compiler can optimize the code better. However, to xp on the subject and understand its subtleties, I used godbolt...

It turned out that the following code does exactly what we expect from it intuitively, since gcc 4.7. Tell me if I'm wrong, but until that version, it doesn't seem to change anything to add -fstrict-aliasing or not with -O3.

```
uint32_t
test(uint32_t arg)
{
  char*     const cp = (char*)&arg;
  uint16_t* const sp = (uint16_t*)cp;

  sp[0] = 0x1;
  sp[1] = 0x1;

  return (arg);
}
```

That is directly an example taken from the article I mentioned. And in the article, it is explained that gcc considers `cp` and `sp` to be two differents objects due to the strict aliasing rule. So, it just leaves `arg` unchanged. That is what happened in older versions of gcc, if I refer to godbolt. But not anymore. Has gcc changed something about the strict aliasing rule in its 4th version? Is it described somewhere? Or am I wrong?

I also checked the following code, and again, strict aliasing or not, it doesn't impact the result. Even using the `restrict` keyword. I hope to understand correctly what this means.

```
void my_loop(int *n, int x)
{
    while (--x)
        printf("%d", *n);
}
```

From that piece of code, I was expecting to see the compiler loading `n` once, and use the value for each iteration. Instead, I noticed that `n` is de-referenced each time I print. Did I miss something?

Comment: `-fstrict-aliasing` is the default setting for GCC with optimizations enabled (`-O2` and above). Your code has undefined behavior in the sense of the C standard for the aliasing violation as well as practical undefined behavior on GCC as long as you don't use `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: `my_loop()` is not thread-safe.  Does that matter?

Comment: *It turned out that the following code does exactly what we expect from it intuitively*  Undefined behavior can do that.  That doesn't make the code correct.  *I also checked the following code, and again, strict aliasing or not, it doesn't impact the result.*  That is wrong.  You merely never **observed** the result being impacted.

Comment: The performance benefits of strict aliasing are highly dependent upon the extent to which programmers try to improve efficiency without it.  One could contrive code such that enabling strict aliasing would offer an order-of-magnitude performance improvement, but in most such cases a little effort would allow comparable performance improvements to be achieved by eliminating redundant memory operations in the source code.  On the flip side, type punning can sometimes offer performance benefits in the `-fno-strict-aliasing` dialect that would be unavailable in strictly conforming C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is what happened in older versions of gcc, if I refer to godbolt. But not anymore. Does gcc changed something about the strict
> aliasing rule in its 4th version? Is it described somewhere? Or am I
> wrong?

No, nothing has changed. It is undefined behaviour (UB) and the compiler is not obliged to behave in a particular way. It is exactly what you observe.

You can achieve the same level of optimization without using pointer punning and invoking undefined behaviour:

```
uint32_t test1(uint32_t arg)
{
    union 
    {
        uint32_t arg;
        uint16_t arg2[2];
    }c = {.arg = arg};

    c.arg2[0] = 0x1;
    c.arg2[1] = 0x1;
    return (c.arg);
}

uint32_t test2(uint32_t arg)
{
    unsigned char *ptr = &arg;
    memcpy(ptr, (uint16_t[]){1}, sizeof(uint16_t));
    memcpy(ptr + 2, (uint16_t[]){1}, sizeof(uint16_t));
    return arg;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nM3rEKocr

Your second example is a valid C code.

Comment: The Standard makes no distinction between "valid C code" and "invalid C code".  It merely defines a three-way partition of source texts into the category of "strictly conforming C programs", which excludes any program to accomplish any task not accommodated by the Standard, "conforming C programs" that are not "strictly C programs", which encompasses any source text that isn't a conforming C program but is nonetheless accepted by at least conforming implementation somewhere in the universe, and source texts which no conforming C implementation anywhere in the universe will accept.

Answer (score 3):

> Does gcc changed something about the strict aliasing rule in its 4th version?

It's important to understand that the strict aliasing rule is a provision of the C language specification (every version), not of GCC or other compilers.  The part that's up to compilers is what they do about it -- in particular, whether they engage optimizations that are safe for programs that comply, but not necessarily safe for those that don't.

> Is it described somewhere?

The SAR or GCC's behavior with respect to it?

The [C23](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf) version of the SAR is paragraph 6.5/7 of that specification:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned
>   type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the
>   object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

The specifics of GCC's optimizations in this area are not documented in its manual.  There is a master switch, `-f`[`no-`]`strict-aliasing`, that controls them, but [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) is vague about the effects:

> Allow the compiler to assume the strictest aliasing rules applicable to the language being compiled. For C (and C++), this activates optimizations based on the type of expressions. In particular, an object of one type is assumed never to reside at the same address as an object of a different type, unless the types are almost the same. For example, an `unsigned int` can alias an `int`, but not a `void*` or a `double`. A character type may alias any other type.

However, with respect to

> it doesn't seem to change anything to add -fstrict-aliasing or not with -O3.

... no, it wouldn't, because the manual also specifies:

> The `-fstrict-aliasing` option is enabled at levels `-O2`, `-O3`, `-Os`.

If you are optimizing at level `-O3`, then adding `-fstrict-aliasing` has no additional meaning.  However, you might then see a difference by turning strict-aliasing analysis *off* via `-fno-strict-aliasing`.  Or you might not.  The compiler is not obligated to perform any particular optimization in any particular case.

---

> I also checked the following code, and again, strict aliasing or not,
> it doesn't impact the result. Even using the restrict keyword, I hope
> to understand correctly what it means.
>
> ```
> void my_loop(int *n, int x)
> {
>     while (--x)
>         printf("%d", *n);
> }
> ```
>
> From that piece of code, I was expecting to see the compiler loading n once, and use the value for
> each iteration. Instead, I noticed that n is de-referenced each time I
> print. Do I miss something?

Aliasing analysis has no bearing on that particular code.  Supposing that `n` is a valid pointer at all, it cannot point to `x` on function entry because `x` is local to the function.  I cannot speak to the specifics of why GCC does not perform the optimization you were looking for, but perhaps it is trying to accommodate the possibility that `*n` is modified by another thread.

Comment: For the last example, I guess it is more likely that GCC is just not using knowledge about the specific behavior of `printf` to exclude the possibility that it writes to where `n` points through a another pointer path. It doesn't need to accommodate another thread modifying it, since that would be a data race.

Comment: That's possible, @user17732522.  I don't know about "more likely".  *C language semantics* don't require it to accommodate the possibility of modification by another thread, but this is a potential quality-of-implementation matter.  And `printf` *does* have synchronization semantics relative to other accesses to `stdout`, and specific implementations might have additional synchronization behavior, so it is not necessarily the case that modification of `*n` by another thread would be racy at the implementation level.

Comment: It's also important to note that constraints in the C Language Standard are only applicable to *strictly* conforming programs, and that the Standard makes no effort to require that all implementations be suitable for all tasks.  Implementations designed to be suitable for various tasks will extend the language by supporting useful constructs that facilitate those tasks, without regard for whether the Standard would require that all implementations do so.

Answer (score 1):

> Is strict aliasing still something to think about in C?

Yes.

> It turned out that the following code does exactly what we expect from it intuitively, since gcc 4.7.

We want to write programs that we want to "guarantee" that will work correctly.

The thing about "guarantee", is that you can't prove that *all possible infinite* programs that have strict alias violation will behave properly by presenting one example that does. That the presented program "works as you expect it to", does not prove that all possible programs with strict alias violation work as you expect them to.

Happily (for me writing this answer) to disprove the contrary I just have to give *one* counterexample where a program with strict aliasing does *not* behave as expected. The web is full of such.

Modifying your code ever, so slightly results in a program exits with 0 exit that status with `-O0`, but with 1 exit status with `-O2`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t test(uint32_t *arg) {
  char*     const cp = (char*)arg;
  uint16_t* const sp = (uint16_t*)cp;
  arg[0] = 1;
  sp[0] = 0;
  sp[1] = 0;
  return arg[0];
}
int main() {
    uint32_t arg;
    return test(&arg);
}
```

> Has gcc changed something about the strict aliasing rule in its 4th version? Is it described somewhere? Or am I wrong?

Even if it did, reasoning about the behavior of a program with undefined behavior is moot. The behavior is undefined, the change in behavior you are observing may be something completely unrelated. GCC does not have to test or care about invalid programs.

Comment: OF course, implementations are allowed to, on a quality-of-implementation basis, extend the semantics of the language by specifying how they will behave in situation where the Standard *waives jurisdiction*, and it's possible to reason about the behavior of a program on such quality implementations.  Indeed, the Committee itself engaged in such reasoning on page 44-45 of the published C99 Rationale. https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The "strict aliasing rule", as processed by clang and gcc, is applicable to programs which perform some kinds of tasks and are intended to be maximally portable, but is not intended to be applicable to programs that need to do things for which the Standard makes no particular accommodation.

When the C Standard was ratified, it was understood as being intended to allow implementations to perform various optimizations which might affect program behavior in corner corner cases, but would not adversely affect what their customers needed to do.  Nobody worried about whether the Standard mandated support for all of the corner cases that implementations might need to uphold in order to be suitable for various tasks, because compiler writers were expected to be more responsive to their customers' needs than the Committee ever could.

The Standard may be viewed as being a three-in-one specification:

1. One for a language which is suited only for the kinds of tasks that could be supported by all implementations for all platforms, and was thus limited to the capabilities of the least capable implementation.
2. One where the value of any object whose address was observable would at all times be encapsulated in the storage at that address, with all actions that read the object observing the bits in the storage, and all actions that write the object setting the bits in the storage.
3. One where a compiler given a construct like:

   ```
    int x;
    int test(double *p)
    {
      x=1;
      *p=2;
      return x;
    }
   ```

   would not need to allow for the possibility that a pointer `p` which has no apparent relationship with anything of type `int` might modify an object of that type, but where any non-garbage compiler given a construct like:

   ```
    void adjust_float_bits(float *p)
    {
      *(unsigned short*)p += 0x80;
    }
   ```

   would recognize that code was doing something weird with a pointer of type `float*`, and thus allow for the possibility that objects of that type might be modified between the pointer conversion and the next time they are accessed using type `float`.

Unfortunately, while #3 would be the most useful language, the maintainers of clang and gcc insist that because the Standard does not require that even the most garbage-quality implementation handle scenarios like those described in #3, programmers have an obligation to jump through hoops to accommodate compilers that are willfully blind to such possibilities.

If a program can easily do everything it needs to do while conforming to the abusive gcc/clang interpretation of the "strict aliasing rule", writing it in a fashion which does so may be useful, but if there's any possible way to twist the words of the Standard so as to break a piece of code, any useful behavior clang and gcc might produce when not using `-fno-strict-aliasing` should be viewed as happenstance.

Consider, for example, the rule "If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value."  As interpreted by clang and gcc, from the point of view of each write access, the phrase "subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value" applies to all subsequent read accesses performed on the storage within its lifetime, even if there are intervening writes using other types.  Any read using an lvalue that would not be compatible with *all* types used to write the storage invokes UB.

For many tasks, a rule that means that any storage which has been written using two or more types can no longer be read via any non-character types would pose no problem.  Thus, the Standard allows implementations *that are intended solely for such tasks* to impose such a rule.  That does not imply any judgment, however, as to whether an implementation that employs such a rule should be deemed suitable for any other task, or whether programmers needing to perform other tasks should be expected to obey that rule.

The rule is as applicable today as it has ever been, for that narrow subset of tasks compatible with the clang/gcc interpretation.  For many other tasks, a weaker version of the rule may have been applicable when using commercial compilers, but the rule has never been relevant when using clang or gcc, since they would require the use of `-fno-strict-aliasing` regardless of whether code would be compatible with an interpretation of the rule that was consistent with the tasks to be performed.

Comment: But strict aliasing violations have been undefined behavior in C [for 34 years](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.3).  You're calling compilers that don't allow programmers to get away with writing code that invokes undefined behavior  "garbage-quality implementation[s]".  That seems to me to be unwarranted and over-the-top as compilers have evolved and improved from the middle of the last century.  GCC was released 36 years ago, and C hasn't really changed all that much (yeah, GCC bodged FAMs...), so I'd expect it to be pushing the limits of the language after almost 4 decades.

Comment: Only in the first dialect described above.  The Standard has *waived jurisdiction* over the construct for 34 years, but has never forbidden it except in strictly conforming programs.  Support for non-portable constructs beyond those mandated has always been a quality of implementation issue.  Many tasks which can be easily accomplished using freestanding implementations that process the second or third language described above would be impossible on freestanding implementations that process the first.

Comment: If thew Standard were to recognize a category of implementations that are suitable for low-level programming, and specify that if a program starts with `#ifdef __IDENTIFIER_TBD`/`#error Unsuitable compiler configuration`/`#endif`, an implementation would be required to either process the program in a manner suitable for low-level programming or reject it entirely, then it could deprecate reliance upon low-level programming constructs in programs that lack such a prologue.  If the Standard had done that 34 years ago, that prologue would probably be on 99% of the programs that would need it...

Comment: ...by now.  The real number of years programmers have had to make systems code be strictly conforming isn't 34 years, but zero.

Comment: //so I'd expect it to be pushing the limits of the language after almost 4 decades// It's been observed that every program has at least one bug and can be shrunk by at least one instruction, and that one may thus conclude that every program can be reduced to a single instruction that doesn't work.  To that observation, I would like to add mine: clang and gcc are in a race to find that instruction.